# caching in hibernate on glassfish

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I am trying to implement a second-level cache in my hibernate application but I am getting the following exception when I try to get a `SessionFactory`

```
On-the-fly creation of JCache Cache objects is not supported [model.entity.Comment]
```

I have the following config in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
    true
</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
    org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
</property>
```

And a `ehcache.xml` in `src/main/resources`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir/ehcache" />

    <defaultCache maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" eternal="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
                  maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000" diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
                  memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" statistics="true">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

With the dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

And I just cannot seem to get this working properly. 
The model is annotated like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Comment {
```

Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

***EDIT***

I modified the config, by adding this property to `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName">ehcache.xml</property>
```

This made a difference, which is nice and makes it seem as if the config was completely disregarded.

However it did not solve the problem as it now throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cache provider not started
```